# compare dates in javascript not working properly

Tags: javascript, asp.net

Hi all I am using the following script to compare the dates that user selected using devexpress date

```
function compareDate(s, e) {
        var date1 = dateStartDate.GetDate();
        date1 = date1.format("dd/MM/yyyy"); 13/08/2013
        var date2 = dateEndDate.GetDate(); //28/07/2013
        if (date2 != null) {
            date2 = date2.format("dd/MM/yyyy");
            if (date2.toString() === date1.toString()) {
                e.IsValid = true;
            }
            else {
                if (date2 < date1) {
                    e.IsValid = false;
                }
                else {
                    e.IsValid = true;
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

But when I am having these two dates `13/08/2013` and `28/07/2013` this is returning true can some one help me

Comment: Where do you get the dates? They aren't in the parameters for the function.

Comment: @NoLifeKing: Implied global mess is just bound to be an issue here. Maybe not now, but some day... ;-)

Answer (score 0):

You are not comparing dates, you are comparing strings lexicographically (character by character). The string representations of these two dates are in this order: `"13/08/2013" < "28/07/2013"` since `"1" < "2"`

What you want is comparing the Date objects themselves in the same way:

```
var a = new Date();
var b = new Date();
console.log(a < b); // true
console.log(a > b); // false
```

Answer (score 0):

By far the easiest method is to subtract one date from the other and compare the result.

```
var oDateOne = new Date();
var oDateTwo = new Date();

alert(oDateOne - oDateTwo === 0);
alert(oDateOne - oDateTwo < 0);
alert(oDateOne - oDateTwo > 0);
```

[See this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/492994/compare-dates-with-javascript)